# ul list with colums, without using DIVs or Tables

Tags: html, css, list, indentation

So, I'm wondering if it is possible to create a list that would have two columns per list item, much like you could easily simulate in a word document:

[image]

I know I could probably create a table, or two wrapping DIVSs, but I was wondering if there was a different solution that would achieve the same thing simply with CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code block

```
<style>
li label {
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 120px;
}
</style>


<ul>
  <li><label>First Name</label> John</li>
  <li><label>Last Name</label>  Doe</li>
  <li><label>Address</label>  21, Street Address 1</li>
<ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can force the first part of the `<li>` to have a specific with

```
<ul>
   <li><b style="width : 100px; display:inline-block;">Text one</b> Next Column
   <li><b style="width : 100px; display:inline-block;">Text 2</b> Bla Bla
   <li><b style="width : 100px; display:inline-block;">The Indent</b> Is Set
   <li><b style="width : 100px; display:inline-block;">But I'm not</b> Using DIVs
</ul>
```

**Or more simply**

```
<style type="text/css">
ul.xoxo b {
    width   : 100px;
    display : inline-block;
    }
</style>



<ul class="xoxo">
   <li><b>Text one</b> Next Column
   <li><b>Text 2</b> Bla Bla
   <li><b>The Indent</b> Is Set
   <li><b>But I'm not</b> Using DIVs
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm afraid setting a width to `<B>` doesn't work on its own. However all it needs is  `display:inline-block;` and it's good! So great idea =)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ul {
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
     -moz-column-count: 2;
     -o-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
}
```

Refer [Link](http://alistapart.com/article/multicolumnlists)

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hwzpy/)